# Store div content in PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am storing the result of some calculations in a HTML `div` element using the `innerHTML` attribute:

```
var result = document.getElementById('duration').innerHTML+
               obj1+"    "+obj+"    "+
               km.toFixed(1)+" Km     "+Date

document.getElementById('duration').innerHTML = result
```

Now I want to store the `div`'s content/data in a PHP variable.

Comment: I am not sure if you can do that! Javascript, if you are not using Node.js, lives on the browser side, you need to interact with the server side, so you need to make a request to store the data somehow.

Comment: Why don't you separate view data from calculation data, submit the calculated data via ajax and then create the div needed surrounding your calculated data.

Comment: using AJAX is the better option. You need to pass all the values from calculations to the server page and there you need to echo  the html part and catch that in AJAX response.

Answer (score 1):

After set dic content, use jQuery to send data to PHP:

```
var url = 'myPHPFile.php';

$.post(url, {data: document.getElementById('duration').innerHTML});
```

In your PHP , get your variables from $_POST['data']:

```
<?php
    $data = $_POST['data'];
?>
```

Comment: Providing all you are doing is submitting data, you should be using POST. GET is for requesting data which we aren't doing. They can also be cached which might not be desirable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is on client side, so you can try to send JS variable (div content) back via URL and then obtain it via PHP.
JS like this:

```
window.location.href=”index.php?divContent=" + document.getElementById('duration').innerHTML;
```

And then in PHP obtain it from GET, like this:

```
$somevar = $_GET["divContent"];
```